# Updating part of page with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using ASP.NET MVC 5, I'm trying to get a menu system working where clicking on an entry updates part of the page without doing a complete page refresh. My problem is that the Ajax call works, but refreshes the entire page if I use 'return View()' from the action; I tried 'return PartialView()' but this results in a fresh page with just the partial view rendered.

The menu is in _Layout.cshtml, and the menu item is:

```
@Ajax.MyActionLink(
  "<span class='fa fa-image'></span> Address Book",
  "Test",
  "Test",
  new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "page-content",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
  }
)
```

MyActionLink is as follows: (slightly modified from some code I found here)

```
public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
  this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
  string linkText,
  string actionName,
  string controllerName,
  AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
{
  var targetUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, null, ajaxHelper.RouteCollection,
  ajaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(ajaxHelper.GenerateLink(linkText, targetUrl, ajaxOptions ?? new AjaxOptions(), null));
}

private static string GenerateLink(
  this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
  string linkText,
  string targetUrl,
  AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, 
  IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  var a = new TagBuilder("a") {
    InnerHtml = linkText
  };
  a.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
  a.MergeAttribute("href", targetUrl);
  a.MergeAttributes<string, object>(ajaxOptions.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());
  return a.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
}
```

Target is as follows:

```
<div class="page-content-wrap" id="page-content">
  @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Controller and View are:

```
public class TestController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Test() {
        return View();
    }
}


<p>
    <h1 >Hopfully this test will work!</h1>
    <br />
    <br/>
    <p align="center">Partial View!</p>
</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure what `MyActionLink()` is supposed to be doing that you could not do with the standard `@Ajax.MyActionLink()` (or better still, just with jquery's `.get()` or `.load()` functions) but you should compare the html rendered by both your method and the inbuilt method and check if there are any differences, particularly the `data-ajax` attributes

Comment: The MyActionLink is to get the <Span> tag rendered properly, and I get the same behaviour with @Ajax.ActionLink() anyway. Unfortunately I'm not a web designer, so jQuery etc is not my forte, I just got lumped with it, :(

Comment: If your getting the same result with `@Ajax.ActionLink()` then there a problem with `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` or you have disabled unobtrusive validation - check you have `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` in `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the javascript libraries needed to make Ajax calls working are missing/not loaded. Without them, clicking the link is not caught and the link is working like a normal link.

Comment: Thanks David, but didn't work. I referenced jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js, tried returning both View and PartialView, same result as before.

Comment: Is jquery included also?

Comment: Yep, scripts are as follows:

    jquery-2.1.1.min.js,
    jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js,
    jquery-ui.min.js,
    bootstrap.min.js

Comment: What does your html look like? It should look something like this: <a href="/Home/Test" data-ajax-update="#target" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">Test</a>
Works fine here, unless jquery or jquery.unobtrusive-ajax is missing.

Comment: Did you by any chance update jQuery, but not jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax? I updated a test project to jQuery 2.1.1 and then it was also broken. After updating jquery.ubobtrusive.ajax it worked again.

Comment: The rendered HTML is: <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#page-content" href="/Test/Test"><span class="fa fa-image"></span> Address Book</a>.   I got the ajax js library through NuGet, which says all are up to date. The source doesn't give any version number.

Comment: Did you check to make sure jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax is actually loaded using IE/Chrome developer tools? Did you add jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax in the BundleConfig file? If so, make sure to include jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax.js and not jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax.min.js, the latter will not work in debug mode.

Comment: Yep, the scripts are loading all ok. Tested in Chrome, IE, and FF. Changed the libraries to full versions, not the minified ones. The files are loaded in the _Layout file, tried at bottom and in the <head> section. No luck :(   I need to go to bed, will pick this up  tomorrow. Thanks for you help, much appreciated!